# Help finding sum of infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The question asks to find the sum of the series $1000+1-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{9}{25}-\frac{27}{125}+...+(\frac{-3}{5})^n+...$

So what is throwing me off is the 1000. The other terms are geometric with a  $\frac{-3}{5}$ ratio. So, I found out that $1-\frac{3}{5}+\frac{9}{25}-\frac{27}{125}+...$ sums to $\frac{5}{8}$. To solve the problem would I just need to add $1000$ to $\frac{5}{8}$, or is it not that simple.

Comment: Yes, it's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is that simple.  You can split off any finite number of terms at the start of a sum, add them up, and sum the resulting series.  In fact, the way I would represent your series is $1000 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac {-3}5)^n$ but you could (somewhat perversely) represent it as $1000 + 1 -\frac 35 +\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\frac {-3}5)^n$ and sum that for the same result.